# Helm Variable Chart.Name in Chart.yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Planning to reuse the same helm chart folder for different REST services as we have good template variable support.

So I am able to reference {{.Values.application.name}} almost all the yaml and it is working fine.

However in `Chart.yml` declaring Chart name with {{.Values.application.name}} is giving error.

```
apiVersion: v2
name: {{.Values.application.name}}
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
```

results error with `helm template`

```
Error: cannot load Chart.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{".Values.application.name":interface {}(nil)}
helm.go:84: [debug] error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{".Values.application.name":interface {}(nil)}
cannot load Chart.yaml
```

Not sure how to resolve this.
Please help.

---

If there is no helm support for this, then I will go with the below, before running the helm upgrade for every service.

```
 sed -i "s|SERVICE_NAME|$SERVICE|g" helm-package/Chart.yaml
```

and `Chart.yml`

```
---
apiVersion: v2
name: SERVICE_NAME
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
```

Comment: Chart.yaml cannot be templated

Comment: Thanks! @OneCricketeer, any workaround for this?

Comment: You can reuse a chart without uniquely naming it, and it cannot otherwise reference any values. It's not clear from the question how the name is being used otherwise

Comment: I have common concourse pipline for all the services, pipeline know the SERVICE_NAME, so before running the helm, I want to update the Chart.Name also same as SERVICE_NAME.

Comment: I'm not familiar with concourse, but if you need a unique name, then sed or envsubst can work, sure

Comment: If you're reusing a chart that's completely identical except for `.Chart.Name`, can you have only a single copy of the chart and deploy it multiple times with different parameters?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, I am doing exactly same. Thanks!